# Querying Relationships in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am having issues trying to query an Eloquent relationship.

I have 2 tables

**tbl_deals**

- id
- deal_id
- merchant_id

**tbl_merchants**

- id
- merchant_id
- merchant_url_text

I defined a deal model as

```
class deal extends Model
{
    public function merchant() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\merchant', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }
}
```

Now, I want to query all deals based where merchant_url_text = a variable in my controller

Here's what I am trying

```
$deals = deal::with('merchant')->get(); //Retrieving all the deals with merchants
```

If I return $deals its giving me all deals with merchant relationship.

How do I constraint the deals by saying where merchant_url_text = $variable

I am trying

```
return $deals->where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)->get();
```

but it is giving me an error saying :

> "Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in ..."

I tried to lookup the documentation for querying relationships in Laravel Docs. It talks about this example

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->posts()->where('active', 1)->get();
```

In this case, its trying to get the first user and finding corresponding posts related to the user.

In my case I want to filter from all deals, the deals that have merchant_url_text = a specific variable in my controller.

Any help on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
$specific_merchant_url_text = "i don't know";
$deals_with_specific_merchant_url_text = [];
$deals = deal::with('merchant')->get();

foreach($deals as $deal)
     if( $deal->merchant->merchant_url_text==$specific_merchant_url_text)
          array_push($deals_with_specific_merchant_url_text, $deal);
```

So you get array of deals with specific merchant url text in `deals_with_specific_merchant_url_text`.

Another approach using `DB` object :

```
$deals = DB::table('deals')
        ->join('merchants', 'deals.merchant_id', '=', 'merchants.id')
        ->select('deals.*')
        ->where('merchants.merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
        ->get();
```

Yours with `raw` :

```
$deals = deal::selectRaw('tbl_deals.*')
         ->Join('merchants','deals.merchant_id','=','merchants.merchant_id')            
         ->where('merchants.merchant_url_text', '=', $merchant_url_text) ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked. Had to change merchant() to merchant in the if statement. Is this a recommended approach to perform such an operation? I could just do a simple join with the table using select raw too. Do you know which one would be more efficient?

Comment: $deals = deal::selectRaw('tbl_deals.*')
              ->Join('merchants','deals.merchant_id','=','merchants.merchant_id')
              ->where('merchants.merchant_url_text', '=', $merchant_url_text)
              ->get(); This also works. Any idea if this approach is more efficient than your approach to loop through all records to constraint?

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure really in the term of performance which of the three is the perfect for such operation, but i recommended one of the last two, good luck, and if you find my answer helpful vote it up if it answer your question mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

With takes a callback. This will bring back all deals but only eager load merchants that match.

```
$deals = Deal::with(['merchant' => function ($query) use ($url_text){
    return $query->where('merchant_url_text', $url_text);
}])->get();
```

Flip-side: if you only want deals with a matching merchant, use where has.

```
$deals = Deal::whereHas('merchant', function ($query) use ($url_text){
    return $query->where('merchant_url_text', $url_text);
})->get();
```

If you want both, chain them:

```
$deals = Deal::whereHas('merchant', function ($query) use ($url_text){
    return $query->where('merchant_url_text', $url_text);
})->with(['merchant' => function ($query) use ($url_text){
    return $query->where('merchant_url_text', $url_text);
}])->get();
```

I capitalized deal because it's standard. It wasn't capitalized in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder join query .

```
    DB::table('tbl_merchants')
         ->join('tbl_deals', 'tbl_merchants.merchant_id', '=','tbl_deals.merchant_id')
         ->where('tbl_merchants.merchant_url_text',$merchant_url_text)
         ->get();
```